# How is the network hash rate calculated?

Tags: hash, charts

Miners work on finding blocks but don't sent anything until they find the block.

Considering that, how can sites like [bitcoincharts.com](http://bitcoincharts.com/bitcoin/) display a graph of the network hash rate?

Comment: If I flip a fair coin repeatedly, and tell you that I found 1 billion heads, it's (practically) statistically certain that I flipped the coin very nearly 2 billion times. The same sort of extrapolation can determine the total network power based on the success rate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The hashrate can be calculated from the expected rate of finding a block (144 a day), the actual rate of finding a block and the current difficulty.

So let's calculate the average hash_rate for a single day:

```
expected_blocks = 144
difficulty = 11187257.461361 # this is on May 22nd 2013
blocks_found = 155 # Also May 22nd 2013
hash_rate = (blocks_found/expected_blocks*difficulty * 2**32 / 600)
```

The reason we use a day to average out the hash_rate is that taken block by block the variance would be really high and we would not get anything meaningful.

According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28155/144%2a11187257.461361%20%2a%202%2a%2a32%20/%20600%29%20byte%20/%20second) this gives us an averagge hash_rate for the 22nd May 2013 of 86.19 THashes/s. Numbers of course may vary depending on how you chose your interval, which appears to be the reason numbers don't match with the ones on [Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate)

Comment: I know this answer was given 5 years ago, but why 2**32? I'm presuming it has something to do with the 256-bit hashing function used, but some clarification would be awesome :)

Comment: @glowkeeper see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30225/60443

Comment: Thanks, @JBaczuk! Looks good! I should probably check that answer against mine (https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79774/estimated-number-of-hashes), but I'm currently knee-deep in code, so I'll report back later, once I've done some back-of-the-envelope-calc's :)

Answer (score 7):

The network hash rate can be statistically inferred from the difficulty and the rate at which blocks are found. It's just a more complex version of the fact that if you know that someone is flipping coins and heads comes up 800 times an hour, they're flipping about 1,600 coins an hour.